# vba problem with counting consecutive cell repeated value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long list of column of numbers that go from 0 to 360, something like this:

```
54
54
53
53
53
...
...
2
2
2
1
1
1
0                                   1
0  
0
0
0
1
1
2
2
2
....
...
359
359
0                                   2
0
0
```

what I want is that if there is a list of consecutive rows of 0, then it counts as 1 and then goes on to find the next consecutive rows of 0 then it keeps counting as 2 and so on.

How do I code this, please help, thanks

trying to find algorithm that count repeated value in consecutive rows only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Office 365 you could also use SCAN:
`=SUM(N(SCAN(,A1:A16,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b=0,a+1,0)))=1))`

Change the range to your needs

In older Excel you can use this in `B2` assuming the range starts at `A2`:
`=IF(OR(A1,A1="")*EXACT(A2,0),IFERROR(LOOKUP(9^9,B$1:B1,B$1:B1+1),1),"")`
Drag this down.

Comment: thanks guy, unfortunately I use the old version of excel, 2016 and can't use those ideas suggested except some coding, appreciate it

Comment: Edited a possible Excel 2016 solution

Comment: I have these numbers in column I only, and let say I want it to count and put in the column J, then not sure why the formula has A1, A2, B1,B2?

Comment: As I mentioned all the numbers are in column I only, and I used your formulas in column J as =IF(OR(I1,I1="")*EXACT(I2,0),IFERROR(LOOKUP(9^9,I$1:I1,I$1:I1+1),1),""), it doesn't return anything!!!

Comment: `=IF(OR(I1,I1="")*EXACT(I2,0),IFERROR(LOOKUP(9^9,J$1:J1,J$1:J1+1),1),"")` the Idea is: if - either the cell above `I2` contains a number or is blank - and `I2` equals `0` than lookup the last value in column J prior to the current row and add 1 to that number. If the conditions are not met return a blank. The formula would start at `J2`

Comment: It works finally!!! Thanks so much mate, really appreciate it :)

Comment: Note that this works from the second cell. If the first could also be a zero, we need to make some adjustments. Also, if you think this solved your question, please hit the ✔️ left from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As formula (works only for Office365 as it uses `Let`)

```
=LET(x;IF(AND(A2=0;A1<>0);1;0);IF(x=1;SUM(B$1:B1)+1;""))
```

(Assumes that your numbers start at A2).

The first `IF` "marks" all cells with 1 when they contain a 0 and the cell above is not 0. The second `IF` checks if this value is 1 and if yes, sums up all values that are above (and add 1).

Comment: `=IF(IF(AND(A2=0;A1<>0);1;0)=1;SUM(B$1:B1)+1;""))` would work without LET. It will give false returns for  blanks followed by `0` though.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
Sub Doit()

Dim Thing As Range
Dim zCount As Integer
Dim iLastRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set Thing = Range("A1")
iLastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Thing.Select

For i = 0 To iLastRow - 2
    
    If Thing.Offset(i, 0) = 0 And Thing.Offset(i + 1, 0) = 0 Then
    
        Thing.Offset(i, 0).Select
        zCount = zCount + 1
        Thing.Offset(i, 1).Value = zCount
    
        Do Until Thing.Offset(i + 1, 0) <> 0 Or i > iLastRow - 2
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        
    End If

Next

End Sub
```